# selenium phpunit: use function from another class

Tags: selenium, phpunit

I am using selenium 2 with phpunit.
I've created a class that tests a search in my site. Now, I'm trying to create another class that checks my QA branches. From this class, I'm trying to call a function that exists in the search test class. 
I've got this error:

> "There is currently no active session to execute the 'byId' command.
>   You're probably trying to set same option in setUp() with an incorrect
>   setter name. You may consider using setUpPage() instead."

I want be able to call another function from other test classes. This is my code:

```
class TestQAbranch extends TestGeneral{

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->setHost('localhost');
        $this->setPort(4444);
        $this->setBrowser('firefox');
        $this->setBrowserUrl( 'mysite.com' );
   }

   public function testBranch()
   {
       $this->url('index.php');

       //test saerch
      $testSearch = new TestSearch();
      $testSearch->searchSpecificPairs( array( 'GOOG' => 1 ));
   }
}



class TestSearch extends TestGeneral
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->setHost('localhost');
        $this->setPort(4444);
        $this->setBrowser('firefox');
        $this->setBrowserUrl( 'mysite.com' );
    }

                 . . .
                 . . .
                 . . .
                 . . .

    public function searchSpecificPairs( $specific = array() )
    {
        if( empty( $specific ))
            $specific = self::$specificPairs;
        foreach( $specific as $pairName => $searchTable )
        {
            parent::byId('searchTextTop')->value( $pairName );
                  ...
                  ...
                  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The session is not created when trying to access the code from another file. Create a new session using
    `$this->prepareSession();`